# How to change password on a wallet created with simplewallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, security

I have created a wallet using simplewallet, but I am not satisfied with the password.
How do I go about changing the password on the wallet?

(I am running monero.linux.x64.v0-9-4-0)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far I know, this is not possible. You have to restore you account with 
`simplewallet --restore-deterministic-wallet` and give a new password.

Comment: i did so but ended up with empty password. Now i have to set a new one. How?

Comment: Haven't you been prompted for a password?

Answer (score 0):

This will soon be possible with new changes with the 0.10.2 release. According to the [changelog](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5vsmom/psa_monero_0102_is_out_and_is_a_strongly/):

> added a change_password command to monero-wallet-cli

The command for simplewallet/monero-wallet-cli is not available yet, but the code is partially there. Expect this feature soon.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was a bit overeager. There is preliminary code for this, but no user command yet. It should be there soon though :)

Answer (score 0):

Short of restoring your wallet from seed or keys, this is not possible yet. This is planned soon, however.